# How to create a list of a range with incremental step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, increment

I know that it is possible to create a list of a range of numbers:

```
list(range(0,20,1))
output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

but what I want to do is to increment the step on each iteration:

```
list(range(0,20,1+incremental value)
```

p.e. when incremental = +1

```
expected output: [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: When `incremental_value` is one, the result would be `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]`. Or do you want to increment the step by one _on each iteration_?

Comment: @ForceBru, your right. What I want is to add the incremental value to the step to become the new step value p.e. step = 1+1 =2, new step =2, new step = 3, new step = 4 etc. Yes increment the step by one on each iteration.

Comment: Either use a `while` loop, or a generator (generators can store state of `step`, whereas iterators can't) as per the top-two answers here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible, but not with `range`:

```
def range_inc(start, stop, step, inc):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step
        step += inc
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
def incremental_range(start, stop, step, inc):
    value = start
    while value < stop:
        yield value
        value += step
        step += inc

list(incremental_range(0, 20, 1, 1))
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Comment: Thanks Batman, you gave the same answer as ForceBru. I gave the acceptance to his answer only because he was 1 minute earlier :) However I appreciate your answer very much.

Answer (score 5):

Even though this has already been answered, I found that list comprehension made this super easy.  I needed the same result as the OP, but in increments of 24, starting at -7 and going to 7.

```
lc = [n*24 for n in range(-7, 8)]
```

Comment: Or this one `list(range(-168, 169, 24))` but it is not what I asked. I asked for an incremental increment. `[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]` `+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+ ....`

Answer (score -1):

I have simplified the above code even further. Think this will do the trick.

```
List=list(range(1,20))
a=0
print "0"
for i in List:
    a=a+i
    print a
```

Specifying the `nth` range, gives you all the numbers with the particular pattern.

Comment: where is b used and why use "l" ? 

"Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names. In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the numerals one and zero. When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead."

(http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)

Also your code doe not output a list, as Reman wanted

Comment: I'm a kinda new to these programming.

Comment: Sure and Thanks Brother